# How to continue patterns in next line when using sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need a little help to continue the pattern in next line when using 'sed'.  It throws it can't read the file for all the pattern (except the first one)

```
cat server.xml | sed -E 's|(jndiName=")[^/]*(/jdbc/WorklightDS")|\1clsapp\2|' \
                        's|(worklightlib_)[^/]*(")|\1clsapp\2|' \
                        's|(libraryRef=")[^/]*(/)|\1clsapp\2|' \
                        's|(jndiName=")[^/]*(/jdbc/WorklightReportDS)|\1clsapp\2|' \
                        's|(resource.dir}/)worklightconsole(/lib")|\1clsapp\2|g'
```

I read that '\' back slash will help us to continue the pattern on next line.

But, unfortunately it does not work as expected and I work on RHEL 6.5 and curious to know the solution

Note:  I was able to replace the value by following a different mechanism.

My input is:

```
<dataSource jndiName="worklightconsole/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false"> OUTPUT ----> <dataSource jndiName="clsapp/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
```

Comment: i can foresee you will have a bunch of error if you try to deal with xml file using regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to start with a small and simple operation before building up to the complex, and when a complex operation fails it is wise to retreat to a simple one.

In this case, if we retreat to this:

```
echo apple | sed -E 's|a|A|' \
                    's|e|E|'
```

we see that the problem persists, and if we retreat further to this:

```
echo apple | sed -E 's|a|A|' 's|e|E|'
```

we discover that the problem has nothing to do with continuing patterns to the next line with a backslash. The problem is that you cannot string commands together like that. I suggest this:

```
echo apple | sed -E -e 's|a|A|' -e 's|e|E|'
```

This works, and so does this:

```
echo apple | sed -E -e 's|a|A|' \
                    -e 's|e|E|'
```

and you can now build back up to your complex case.